# Woocommerce: variation select not triggered correct

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I see another topic with an analog question, but not find answer. I have a custom input view for Variations. I want to trigger stock selection when variations change (for change price, image, and more). When I use stock select variation work correctly. But when I programming change value of select and triggered it "change" then nothing works.

My custom input

```
<input class="radio-custom input_attribute" select_id="<?=$attribute_name?>" name="input_attribute_<?=$attribute_name?>" value="<?=$option?>" type="radio">
```

My Jquery code

```
$(".input_attribute").change(function (){
        $("select#" + $(this).attr("select_id")).val($(this).val()).trigger("change");
    });
```

What do I need to be triggered another selection?